# GitLab and Visual Studio Code integration

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to integrate Visual Studio Code as GitLab to perform version control of a software for my senior project at collegue.

I've tried with this commands.

1. git config --global user.name "xx xxxx"
2. git config --global user.email "xx.xxxx@mail.com"
3. git clone ssh://git@gitlab.com/NewFolder/repo.git

After introducing this commands the terminal shows:

"Cloning into 'state-editor'...
PC@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboar-interactive).
fatal: Cloud not read from remote repository. "

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, you need to make sure you have [added an SSH public key to your GitLab account](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#add-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account), and are properly recognized/authenticated by GitLab with:

```
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com
```

Two, you need to create an empty project on GitLab, for you to clone/access:

```
git clone ssh://git@gitlab.com/<me>/<myRepo>
```

Replace `<me>` with your actual GitLab user account name.
"`NewFolder`" is likely not your GitLab account.